# Reading rows from very large table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to read through all rows from a very large table. However executing `SELECT *`doesn't work, possibly because the table is large `row=1` 1 to `rows=117051923` so when I executed, it keeps running with no result (eventually connection to `postgres` breaks).

```
supplier=> SELECT * FROM my_table;
Killed
$Akil
```

I wouldn't like to use LIMIT/OFFSET because I have to keep setting range of rows to read (image over 117M rows). is there a way to have query run some rows (say in chuck). Purely sql, not implemented in a language.

Comment: "I wouldn't like to use LIMIT/OFFSET because I have to keep setting range of rows" ...if you just make a little script which does that and sets the correct values automatically each time, then it's no hardship really

Comment: If you need to query in "chunks" the LIMIT/OFFSET is the way to go - that **is** "purely SQL".

Comment: The real question here is, why do you want to do this, do your users read fast?

Comment: That is a good point...why do you need to read all of these millions of rows at once? What are you using the results for?

Comment: @Jodrell I actually got to migrate some records to a remote `postgres` server from my localhost.

Comment: @arilwan there is almost certainly a better way of bulk migrating data.

Comment: @ADyson I want to migrate a previously collected sensor dataset to a `postgres` database running on FIWARE, to allow doing big data analysis using and retreival using fiware generic enablers(eg orion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is in psql, you can adjust how many rows are returned at once by adjusting FETCH_COUNT.  This should prevent you from running out of memory.

```
\set FETCH_COUNT 10000
```

Alternatively, use \copy to copy the data into a file and use your favorite pager (less or more) to go through it.

```
\copy my_table TO 'my_table.txt'
```

Comment: This seems a bit precise, I guess then `copy` can then be used to copy as `csv`

Comment: @Jemery after setting the `FETCH_OUT` could the result returns the next 10000, or just the first and stop?

Comment: It will keep going.  Internally, psql is just using a cursor to grab 10000 rows at a time and display them instead of grabbing all rows and trying to format them for display.  It's not entirely clear why you would need to display millions of rows, but using FETCH_COUNT should at least prevent you from running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

In postgres, the best way to do this would be to use a cursor: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_film_titles(p_year INTEGER)
   RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE 
 titles TEXT DEFAULT '';
 rec_film   RECORD;
 cur_films CURSOR(p_year INTEGER) 
 FOR SELECT title, release_year
 FROM film
 WHERE release_year = p_year;
BEGIN
   -- Open the cursor
   OPEN cur_films(p_year);

   LOOP
    -- fetch row into the film
      FETCH cur_films INTO rec_film;
    -- exit when no more row to fetch
      EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

    -- build the output
      IF rec_film.title LIKE '%ful%' THEN 
         titles := titles || ',' || rec_film.title || ':' || rec_film.release_year;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   -- Close the cursor
   CLOSE cur_films;

   RETURN titles;
END; $$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Not an expert on PostgreSQL but in MS SQL Server, this would be a bad idea.